# TFS Alert for check-in by certain users only

Tags: tfs-alerts

I have a team of nine, but four including myself are senior developers.  We don't review each others work, but I'd like to get alerts for check-ins of the junior developers.

The devs here do many many micro-checkins.  So email spams up pretty quick.  However, I can cut that in half if I subscribe to only alerts of the five junior devs.

In the Alert Filters, there are 9 fields, "Committer" is the only thing that could possibly be related to what I want to filter by.  However, I've found articles that say that is not the right field and that the CheckInPolicy/Owner field is the right one.  That isn't an option though.

So how do I receive alerts just for check-ins just for these specific five people?

Comment: I think those articles say that because `Committer` and `Owner` are indeed different things. On TFS, one is able to act in behalf of others, so in this specific case, the Owner and the Committer are going to be different. If that's the case and you filtered by `Committer`, you'll get the wrong guy. If, and only if you're sure that no one can/will check-in in behalf of another developer, I believe you can filter by Committer without worrying much about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and was able to set up this type of alert successfully by using the user's domain username. For example "Committer = MYDOMAIN\DomainUsername"

Comment: This works for a single user, but OP was asking about setting up a notification for multiple people.

Comment: Right, you'd just add a new OR clause for each user in the alert filters.

Comment: It doesn't allow you to add OR clauses on who gets notified, on what items you get notified on.